# Secure API for php functions

Tags: php, ios, api, security, session

I am creating an API for my php functions, so they can be accessed by mobile apps. Each function can be fired up by a specific url where the parameters are also give with this url.

example of a function in my API:

```
<?php
    $function = $_GET['function'];

    if($function == "login"){
        $userName = $_GET['username'];
        $saltedPass = $_GET['pass'];
        //login query
        //return true or false
    }
?>
```

The idea is to fire up this function by a mobile app with a HTTPrequest:

```
$check = HTTPrequest('www.domain.com/functions.php?function=login&username=mike&pass=343iubgfdg34tJHVvr23').read();
if($check == true){
    //login
}
else{
    //wrong username or pass
}
```

But this also means that everyone who knows these specific urls can fire up my functions. How do I secure this the right way?

Thank you

Comment: you have to pass a static unique token from mobile app and check it wihtin php to its access using mobile or not

Comment: Require some form of authorization and authentication to access the URLs, and serve them only over TLS.

Comment: Learn about token. Also, I don't think that its a really good idea to build a login this way... Hope you know a lot about SQL injection & prepared statements. Also its never a good idea to pass passwords in URL.

Comment: Do not pass credentials in query part - send them in headers or by post method so they won't be logged through http server.

Comment: Mandatory reading. [OWASP Rest Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Here is My Experience 
you will need the user to login (at least)

then you stored userid /user email on mobile (browser) or local storage
During the Login , the correspond password for this user will be calculated and send back from the login user

For example : the user id is  abc , using SSL AES128  Encrypthe you will get a long string like ADEXCEFEF0843495340

you put them both user id and the password all together in an array then base64 them,
when sending out to the url , only a base64 token will be send out , I gust it just confuse enough for the beginner to getout how you get it done.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to secure your API's is OAuth2. It's what Google, Facebook, and Twitter to use in order to authenticate first and third party clients such as the webisites and mobile apps. It's a bit complex, but if you can take the time to go through an OAuth2 Server tutorial, you'll thank yourself later on! Have a look here http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/